# C++ Linux code breaks the Windows build because missing headers means the functions are undefined

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I am developing a piece of software in C++ using Visual Studio on Windows. From the beginning, I would like to have it run on both Windows and Linux. Obviously, I won't compile the Linux binary on a Windows machine, but I still want to use Visual Studio to write the code.

When it comes to headers, I am selecting while file to use based on pre-processor definitions.

A very rudimentary and simple example:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PLATFORM_TIMER_H
#define PLATFORM_TIMER_H

#ifdef _WIN32

#include "win32\win32_timer.h"

#elif __linux__

#include "linux\linux_timer.h"

#endif 

#endif // PLATFORM_TIMER_H
```

For the header it works just fine. But the .cpp-file for the Linux implementation breaks the build on Windows. That's because the Linux .cpp-file will get compiled no matter what, even on Windows. And because the Windows machine is missing Linux-headers, the function it uses will be undefined.

Question 1: What is the "industry standard" to deal with this?

Question 2: Is it reasonable to wrap **both** the .h and .cpp-files in "#ifdef PLATFORM" so that the code will only be enabled on the correct OS?

Comment: The #pragma once is not useful here are you already made sure that it would only be compiled once using the PLATFORM_TIMER_H macro. Plus, #pragma once is not universal, especially when you're doing cross-platform.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are using both `#pragma once` and old-style inclusion guards? Edit: just read the previous comment. Also, I have yet to meet a modern compiler that doesn't know how to handle `#pragma once`.

Comment: Your backslashes are wrong. Turn them into slashes.

Comment: @jbeck: It's not unreasonable to use both. The "old-style" inclusion guards will cover all cases where `#pragma once` may fail (e.g. identical files at different paths when network shares are used), whereas `#pragma once` may get you a little speed for the normal cases. Personally, I usually don't bother with `#pragma once` at all. However, I do add generated random hashes to my include guard names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code specific to one operating system needs to have the proper `#ifdef`'s set up, whether in header files or source files.

Comment: So surrounding the source files in #ifdefs is not weird? Thanks for the quick answer! Will accept ASAP

Comment: @Markall Not at all.  Either that, or don't compile the Linux specific files on Windows.

Comment: `#ifdef`s in code are dirty and should be avoided, except for minor tweaks. Implementations should be split into separate files instead, most of the time 2 files are enough: one for windows, another one for unix-like systems.

Answer (score 4):

> But the .cpp-file for the Linux implementation breaks the build on Windows. That's because the Linux .cpp-file will get compiled no matter what, even on Windows.

Why are you compiling the Linux-specific file for a Windows build?

> Question 1: What is the "industry standard" to deal with this?

If you're going to create separate source files for Windows-specific and Linux-specific code, then the whole point would be that you use only the appropriate one for the current platform when you build.

An alternative approach would be to have both implementations in the same source file, using conditional compilation to choose which parts to use. That's pretty conventional, too, especially where the parts that vary are smaller than whole functions.

> Question 2: Is it reasonable to wrap both the .h and .cpp-files in "#ifdef PLATFORM" so that the code will only be enabled on the correct OS?

It would be strange to go to the trouble of creating separate, platform-specific source files and then use conditional compilation to include them all in every build.  It could *work*, but it would not fall within my personal definition of "reasonable".